# Unable to connect to any wifi network detected in Xubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu

I have a HP 620 laptop with Xubuntu 20.04.2 LTS installed. I can see all the Wi-Fi networks available, but unable to connect to any of them. It tries to connect, but I get this error message. `Disconnected - you are now offline`

The passwords are all correct.

This is my network controller.

```
Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3090]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [103c:1453]
Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can click on the network icon in the system tray, and create a new WiFi connection. There you can choose the correct WiFi encryption type and so on. Sometimes Ubuntu cannot automatically configure that.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. You can select the Wi-Fi encryption type by the 'Edit Connections' option in the network icon, right? I checked it and the encryption used is WPA & WPA2 Personal. I tried changing it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you try another driver? It looks like a driver-problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your wireless may be dropping because of power management; that is, the feature where the card partially powers down to save battery power during periods of inactivity and then, ideally, powers back up seamlessly when activity resumes. Let's disable power saving to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Your wireless may be dropping because the channel to which it was connected has suddenly changed.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

Your wireless may be dropping because there are two wireless access points with the same name and password. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Is there any improvement?

Answer (score 0):

```
Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

This is actually not the correct driver (I'm not 100% sure)

[This post](https://www.techytalk.info/ralink-rt3090-ubuntu-driver-ppa/) may fix your problem. There it is described how you can install the correct driver. I did not test this - so if it's not working comment this answer please edit: you have to use another ppa

INFO: you might have to try: 'sudo apt-key update' after you added the repository

INFO: THIS PPA IS NOT ONLINE ANYMORE, [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1476007&highlight=RT3090) another solution:

Comment: https://www.techytalk.info/ralink-rt3090-ubuntu-driver-ppa/ is the This post link

Comment: I tried following the instructions, but I got this error message.                                      E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/markus-tisoft/rt3090/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: do 'sudo apt-key update' please

Comment: The repo isn't online anymore. I don't have a ralink device so I blindly try out